# IPA Wrong version number in archive

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, application-loader

I changed the version for my app in Xcode's "General" settings to be 0.3.0. I saved it and also looked into `Info.plist`, the version was also updated there. But when I archived it and looked for the version number in the generated `.ipa` file, I found it to be the version of the last archive I made for this project (which was 0.2.0). Thus I cannot upload the archive via Application Loader because the build with this version already exists in my iTunesConnect. How can I get Xcode to archive with the correct version number?

Comment: check in itunes connect  in build section if your build already uploaded with this version then it will not allow to you to upload ,

Comment: As I said the Version 0.2.0 ist already in iTunesConnect and it's legit that Application Loader doesn't upload it. The problem is that Xcode archives with the wrong version number.

Comment: try to clean project with shift + option + k

Comment: Just tried it but didn't fix it.

Comment: is your device connect with mac ?

Comment: Yes I have an iPhone for development connected to my Mac.

Comment: remove that and build achieve with generic device.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked for me

Comment: welcome i have add this as answer accept it and  give upvote .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove device if your device connected with mac and build archive with generic device.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I'd update it in "General" but the Info.plist file for release builds hadn't also been updated. Updating it manually there fixed the issue. The "General" tab numbers weren't used at all.